# "Hot Meta Posts" with a 4-digit score wrap onto a second line

Tags: bug, design, community-bulletin

I think this is a bug. In my list of "Hot Meta Posts" there was a random 8 all snuggled up to the previous post, but the 8 post had no name, and I couldn't click on it.

I assume this is a bug:

[image]

It's interesting, I still see this bug looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29796264/is-there-still-a-use-for-inline) but when I look at this meta post everything appears normal:

[image]

Is this somehow context related? I'm running Chrome: 55.0.2883.87 m (64-bit) My monitor resolution is 1920 x 1080.

I notice that the size of the "Hot Meta Posts" box is larger in the http://meta.stackoverflow.com where the 4th digit doesn't wrap. Just regular http://stackoverflow.com has a larger "Hot Meta Posts" box on Internet Explorer too, though "Time to take a stand" has been replaced by this post in the "Hot Meta Post" listing (DOH!) Anyway, it seems to be related to Chrome's small box. I've turned off all my extensions and reloaded the page, but the box size remains the same.

Comment: The score for that first post is 1578, the number just doesn't fit on one line so it's wrapped. It's still a bug, though.

Comment: @Stijn That makes more sense, thanks. Do I need to do anything else here or will someone see and fix this?

Comment: It does not wrap around on me.  Win7 Pro 64 bit, Chrome 55.0.2883.87 m running on a 19" 1440x900 monitor.

Comment: It does for me... Firefox 51, on Debian, 100% zoom.

Comment: @JonathanMee Someone will see this, yes. Whether it'll be fixed is another question :)

Comment: Time to take a stand against Meta posts with 4-digit scores? Anyway, I don't see the wrapping on Safari on OS X nor on Waterfox (one version behind Firefox's current version) on Windows.

Comment: You need to get a bigger screen... :-)

Comment: @baao Interestingly I have a larger screen and the *exact* same setup as NathanOliver and it happens to me and not to him. So potentially, I need a 1440 x 900 screen ;)

Comment: Yeah, the resolution might be more important here.. :)

Comment: The reason why it happens for some people and not for others is almost certainly the fact that  the exact width of the number will depend on the 1) the browser, 2) the OS, 3) the set of installed fonts and 4) the user's font rendering settings, including 5) whether or not subpixel text rendering is enabled. In borderline cases like this one, all of these will combine to determine whether the text will be just narrow enough to fit or just wide enough to wrap.