# Time to lock "Time to take a stand"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, meta, historical-lock

Five days before the posting of this question, [Joel Spolsky](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4/joel-spolsky) posted [Time to take a stand](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342440/time-to-take-a-stand) (yes, it's been only five days!) and all hell broke loose.

- So many answers criticizing the post or suggesting ways to take a stand were posted with [insanely short intervals between each of them.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/342440/timeline)
- [The comment system couldn't handle the intensity of the discussion about the post itself.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/439147)
- [A user with >100k reputation stopped contributing.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/342940)
- [Hot Meta Posts was unable to show the post's score properly.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342634/hot-meta-posts-with-a-4-digit-score-wrap-onto-a-second-line)
- The largest close-reopen war of all time happened - there are more "post closed/reopened/locked/unlocked" notices than there are revisions on [the post's revision history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/342440/revisions?page=1).

Now that the "hype" on Joel's post settled down and [the company made a post about what was learned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342903/well-always-endeavor-to-do-whats-right-well-try-to-do-it-better-next-time), can we please get over this mess by locking the post for historical significance?

Comment: at least [one user](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342561/1070452) has outright quit

Comment: Also, [macroman seems to have quite / stopped contributing as well](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/342615/4639281)

Comment: [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1693593/k3n?tab=profile) seems to be a bit peeved

Comment: It looks like each time it's been locked (or at least the last four times), the unlock has been performed by "Community." Doesn't this mean that it was unlocked automatically somehow? What causes questions to be automatically *un*locked?

Comment: @Kyle many of the locks automatically expire

Comment: @TinyGiant ...but aren't they historical locks? Why would those expire? Also, each unlocking seems to occur on the same day as the lock is applied; is there a reason why locks would expire within hours? It looks like one of the unlocks might have occurred because a moderator forced an edit through (?), but three of them seem to occur right after the post was locked.

Comment: @kyle None of the locks (AFAICT) were historical locks. All of them seem to be content dispute locks. I know that other locks expire after a given timeframe, I'm not sure if this is because the lock itself has a built-in time limit, or that the moderator locking the post has chosen a time limit.

Comment: @KyleStrand No, they were "content dispute" and "off-topic comments" locks. When applying these locks, moderators can set a time limit after which [Community](http://stackoverflow.com/users/-1) removes the lock.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, @TinyGiant and OP. I could have sworn there was a historical lock applied at one point, but I must be mistaken.

Comment: The content dispute locks were applied to stop users from voicing their displeasure with the post ...err I mean closing it.  Some would close it, others - sometime Diamondbacks - would reopen.  When it got hectic they would temporarily lock it to slow the pace.  For a while there were also edit-rollback wars with the more inflammatory language

Comment: @Plutonix to be fair, a few of the locks were due to edit wars.

Comment: [another one bites the dust](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342952/1070452)

Comment: @downvoters Do you think the "hype" on Joel's post not settle down enough to let mods safely lock it?

Comment: And a 106k rep user [leaves as well](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/342940/2617068). Keep in mind that not everyone who decides to stop visiting/contributing over this will make a post/comment/chat/etc. about it (and, as we've seen, [such efforts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342952/1070452) may be closed by high-rep users as off-topic and then deleted by a mod anyway, even though they're directly related to SO).

Comment: Perhaps they were manually unlocked within the database?

Comment: @cybermonkey IMO the team wouldn't go *that* far just to keep a meta post open.

Answer (score -24):

We are [going to implement a new feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290662/were-implementing-an-announcement-tag-for-direct-communication-from-the-team) that treats announcements from us a little differently than other questions. While that's being cooked up, I'm going to lock the post for a week as 'content' dispute, while still on hold, with 3 pending votes to reopen it.

And then I'm going to think about what to do from there, knowing that 2006 people upvoted it, and 370 downvoted. That very well may be a historical lock,  because that preserves it nicely for those 2006 people (and everyone that finds it subsequently), while not further angering the 370 people that won't be able to vote to close it any longer.

We'll talk about it on Monday.

Comment: Question is _not_ on hold, but has been reopened http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342440/time-to-take-a-stand, while still locked (not that it changes anything, but the state of the question described is out of date).

Comment: I support a historical lock. I can't imagine a more perfect case for it.

Comment: I whole-heartedly agree with the content of the original post but I have to ask: why couldn't it just be a blog post? Why implement a new feature?

Comment: @mikec I believe the reasoning was that Meta allows for easier discussion.

Comment: Do you have stats on how many of those 2006 upvotes came from people who visited the site because he linked to it on his twitter (with 140k followers)