# Done with SO and Meta (Lurkness Mode)

Tags: discussion

First I want to say I have faith in SE in general.  I think the work you guys have accomplished is great.  I also have a certain liking to the jobs / careers portion of SO in general.  I have been involved in so many discussions when it comes to UI/UX on these sites that I felt almost like I worked here.

I enjoyed being part of this community and contributing answers (not always the very best) in order to help people become better at what they do - when it comes software development.  I did it because I once remember a time (years and years ago) where I struggled to find the help I needed to learn how to learn the art of programming / design.  Had this site existed 20 years ago I would probably be an even better programmer / designer.

But I cannot honestly say I trust the leadership and the route this company seems to be taking any longer.  I don't agree with a lot of it and when I post answers or questions (on meta) I feel we are dismissed without hesitation.

It's not fair to me or others who have helped shape this community.  Thanks to everyone for the good times.  The bad times.  And the fun of building such a great community.

Lurk Mode Enabled

Comment: For those voting to close, Tim Post has said that Meta is the best way to reach out to the community about community. JonH is talking about community issues here that we've all been a part of this past week. I'm sad to see another member go, but +1 for your message.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg (I didn't vote for anything (not even for your president :-P), but) if everybody who's frustrated or not going to visit parts of the site any more writes a personal "Farewell"-letter, then ... there should be a tag for this. Or... not.

Comment: I've restored this, mostly for the reasons @DavidGrinberg stated in his comment. It's .. okay .. if folks get mad at us because it seems like we're being obstinate or obtuse. It's not okay with me if folks get mad at us for not listening, so this stays.

Comment: @Tim *"It's not okay with me if folks get mad at us for not listening"* Do you mean the getting mad part is not okay, or the not listening part?

Comment: The post doesn't give any fact/link regarding _the route this company seems to be taking_ or _dismissed without hesitation_.

Comment: Did you have anything specific in mind?

Comment: Would love to know how you'd finish this sentence:  I'd come back if ______.

Comment: @Cœur you're welcome to look at the comments, the answers, etc. that JonH has been involved in on the Time to take a stand meta bomb and related questions/answers. Of particular note: his answer to We'll Always Endeavor..., his comment on Pekka's answer to that same question, and his general contributions on the Time to Take... question and its followup question "Should the “Time to take a stand” question be closed / moved?"

Comment: @Jeutnarg About "Time to take a stand", it sounds like adding an historical lock on it could put out the fire.

Comment: @Cœur other minds thought similarly: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342945/time-to-lock-time-to-take-a-stand? I disagree with historical lock for technical reasons, although I certainly wish we could go back in time and change how this all played out.

Comment: I don't mean to suppress your speech or marginalize your views, but it isn't clear to me why this is asked as a separate question, rather than posted as an answer to one of the many communiques from the team members to which it is obviously a response. Posting it as a separate question not only strips it from much-needed context, but also makes me wonder how it should be answered. "This super sucks, sorry to see you go, please don't go?"

Comment: Honestly 20 years ago there was plenty of resources for learning to program, they were called books and believe it not they still exist. Sites like this are not a substitute for picking up a book and teaching yourself, not to mention the many programming resources spread across the World Wide Web. That whole expectation people seem to have is one of the main problems with this site imho.

Comment: Sorry to see you go, but SE platform and its community is pretty much great. But the complains about that post (and also @KyloRen's answer about this community) are exhausting

Comment: @TimPost I'm not sure it's hat you are 'not listening', but not *hearing*. Acknowledging the community regularly, even if it disagrees with your views, would *probably* have a far better effect than flat out ignoring us. I know, in my experience, I've had multiple times where I've tried to reach out to SE (through proper channels) and been flat-out ignored, but then see whatever I asked about get addressed later. Even sending us 'we can probably put this on our radar' is a good start. You expect us to go along with what you say *just because* you're SE, but don't respect our opinion about it.

Comment: Not sure why this is reopened. It doesn't ask a question and it isn't clear what answers are expected. Are you waiting for someone to try and convince you your stated reasons are not correct?

Comment: @MartinSmith It is expected that one would discuss the content of the question. According to "official policy" questions on meta don't have to be questions, or make it clear discussion is expected, what kind of answers are expected, etc.

Comment: @TinyGiant I've voted "unclear what you are asking" because it is. If that is the "official policy" do you have a link and why does that close reason exist on meta?

Comment: @DavidGrinberg JonH isn't really talking *about* community issues. He just mentioned that he doesn't feel the community is listened to. There isn't much that can be discussed here.

Comment: @MartinSmith, even you have to appreciate the, uh, irony, here. *questions on meta don't have to be questions, or make it clear discussion is expected*... pretty much **exactly** what was posted originally (no longer able to be called OP with all the editing) by the CEO.

Comment: @dfd so the evidence for this "policy" is a single somewhat exceptional post?

Comment: @JonH Fwiw I also share your sentiment. In my case I do not have a problem staying involved with the community, the thing that changed for me was I was literally on the verge of applying for a job at SE, a place I have wanted to work for quite some time, and that prospect does not seem appealing to me any more. I cannot see myself being comfortable in an environment with Joel, etc. at the helm (note the HQ is about a 20 minute train commute from my house, and that was where I was hoping to be) given recent events.

Comment: @MartinSmith, yes. When the *single* post comes from the CEO, breaks most rules for what pretty much everyone else has to follow (or be censored by the community), and - after nearly a week of chaos - was edited to actually post something that borders on constructive? Absolutely, yes. Several posts brought up the actual policies that were deviated. (Look, I happen to agree with the message on both the original OP and this OP too. But that sentiment is easily lost - with everyone, not just you - because I happen to disagree with *how* it was delivered.

Comment: @JasonC, I pretty much share your sentiment too. I just couldn't comment a week ago - the atmosphere was extremely toxic. After a day away I decided to avoid the topic (apparently until now) but continue to participate in SO for the real reason I began - to help others. It takes an amount of willful ignorance (and more in the future when they institute a new tag) but with some effort I'm sure I can separate being constructive (helping by answering things I know) from not (reacting to flagrant non-constructive posts from the CEO).

Comment: @RadLexus What About "Time To Take Stand" Post ?

Comment: For what it's worth, [I'm done too](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343055/870604).

Comment: I am sorry to see you go. I know the design team has appreciated your feedback in a lot of product areas. Thank you for your service to the community and your great contribution.