# Nancy's back, so I'm leaving and taking my money with me

Tags: discussion, community

*Who is Nancy?*  More on that later...

> **DISCLAIMER:**
>   *This is a work of fiction. Names, characters, businesses, places, events, locales, and incidents are either the products of the author’s imagination or used in a fictitious manner. Any resemblance to actual persons, living or dead, or actual events is purely coincidental.*

I've decided to quit this community once and for all—[this time for reals](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342952/done-with-so-and-meta-lurkness-mode).  I did a while ago because of issues with the "Jobs" section.  I wasn't a very high rep user, but I contributed a lot of time to the [Jobs section](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A168703%20%5Bjobs%5D), finding over [150 bugs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A168703%20%5Bjobs%5D) (mainly on Jobs).  I didn't get paid for this, but I [did get a thank you from Joel himself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315045/168703).  I have been a member of this community for over ten years, and what I once loved is not something I believe in at all anymore. I will continue to watch, but I won't contribute via time or money (more on the $$$ later...).

So who is Nancy? My previous job, which I had worked at for over 18 years, was my first "real job" I picked up at the end of college.  I loved it, and the company was doing pretty good.  We did have ups and downs because we were in the automotive / manufacturing sector (but that was pretty normal).  Everything in the company was sound until Nancy arrived.

Nancy was the new HR director, and she implemented policies that she herself did not follow.  The old, "do as I say. not as I do" policy.  Enforcing obnoxious rules (OT, punching in and out, start / end times, etc.) while she came in at 10 AM and left by 2 PM each day.  If you had an issue and talked to her about it, she was busy doing her nails or was on her phone texting.  In any event, we went from over 400 employees to 200 within her first year, and then from 200 employees to under 100 employees before she herself escaped.

During that time (the 200 to 100 employees), I myself decided to pick up and leave after 18 years of work (I had no plans to leave; unlike a lot of people in the industry, I do not like job hopping).  Nancy **ruined our community**: we lost good engineers, we lost good programmers, we lost trust, and, finally, many of us lost patience.  What was left were folks holding on for dear life, bless their hearts (many of the folks left over were either getting close to retirement or engineers who just did not want to change).

Here was a workplace people once loved to be at, which ended up being a ghost town. Our shares tanked:

[image: Stock price plot, showing shares decreasing over a span of 1-2 years from a high of ~33 to a low of ~14.]

I quit that job forgetting to take advantage of my flexible health savings account (FSA).  I had over $600 in that account, yet forgot to at least use it on eligible items such as Band-Aids, sun screen, etc.  When I called Nancy a couple of weeks after I had left, stating I had forgotten to use my FSA account money, she mentioned that because I left the company it was terminated and the money went back into the company's account.  I was seriously pissed...

I will not let that happen to me again...and so I am leaving this community and **taking my money with me**.  A new Nancy has arrived, and the money (it's not a lot, but every penny counts) that I spend on my team's [subscription to teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams) will **not be renewed** any longer.

I will not pay for a service backed by people I no longer can trust.  I know, I know..."You're just one customer, Jon...".  You're right; I am one customer, but one customer who used to [compliment and refer other companies to use great products](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380169/thanks-to-so-for-team-devs-designers-pms-etc).  In fact, at my old place I implemented SO for Teams, and at my new place the first thing I implemented was SO for Teams.

**No more, I tell you, because I'm leaving you, Nancy, and I am taking my money with me.**

Thanks for the good times and the bad times.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201049/discussion-on-question-by-jonh-bobs-back-so-im-leaving-and-taking-my-money-wi).

Comment: We now return to our regular Meta programming. (Also, if you feel compelled to heed the template advice in the lock notice, check out Meta Stack Exchange, at your own peril.)

Comment: Poor Alex ... I feel bad for Alex, because here we can see it was Nancy's and Bob's fuckup ... how did blame fall on Alex :(

Comment: I've added a wonderful disclaimer that might help a little bit.

Comment: @JL2210 your last edit leaves the title and the body in an inconsistent state.

Comment: @WaiHaLee That's weird, I clicked "edit" on revision 9.

Comment: @gnat Thanks for bringing such a great post to the attention. I didn't catch it when it was posted. This actually deserves to be featured.

Comment: Why did no one at any time suggest "Pat"?

Answer (score 146, accepted):

So I'm going to answer this even though I already commented to this effect, since the comment thread seems to be full of <s>hand wringing</s> constructive debate...

Let's not dilute what you've done here.  You've decided to vote with your wallet as opposed to with your opinion on Meta.  This is something that can't be ignored and *won't* go unnoticed.

Comment: It definitely got noticed, and apparently couldn't be ignored. The revision history stands testament to that.

Comment: @YvetteColomb:  Jon's zeal of the platform is worth quite a lot...even with Jobs it was worth enough for (then CEO) Joel Splosky to send a swag bag with a signed book.  One thing's for sure: that's likely not a drop in the proverbial bucket.

Comment: @JonH - I can't imagine any reception to your post that would have made you feel better about leaving than the reception it got.  Good travels.