# The Hot Meta Posts vote counter is too narrow

Tags: bug, design, community-bulletin

Following the redesign of the Hot Meta Posts pane, the padding around the vote count is ([still](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342634/hot-meta-posts-with-a-4-digit-score-wrap-onto-a-second-line)) too small, resulting in the vote count closing in on the question title when the vote count exceeds 100:

[image]

This is made even more pronounced if (by chance) the vote count reached four figures (although it doesn't wrap like previously):

[image]

Using:

Windows 10, Google Chrome version 73.0.3683.103 (official build) (64-bit), 3840x2160 screen (with 150% scaling)

Comment: We just have to downvote it twice and problem solved

Comment: 101▲Yes, it looks like more padding is needed if the vote total is at least 100.

Comment: @SterlingArcher Eeek! 8 time more now...

Comment: Lol, https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSP8q.png The time will come...

Comment: We should upvote this post until it reaches a three-digit vote count, as an example to raise awareness

Comment: _A little bit of padding is all I need.._ ;) If it exceeds 3 digits (999 -> 1000), votes could be rounded and displayed as `1.0k`

Comment: I'd almost like to see the vote counts right-aligned. If they got up to 1000 they could go the rep route and use the "k" suffix. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbHgi.png).

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ I concur. Right-aligned counts would be good here – or at least centred ones.

Comment: Adding a `text-align: right` and a `margin-right: 5px` makes for quite a nice look on these.

Comment: Cross-site post on Meta.SE: [Hot Meta Posts titles aren't spaced from vote totals if vote total is a three-digit number](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329468/289905).

Comment: I googled for a sec to ensure this isn't an outlandish question: why not use a table for the entire yellow box? Autosizing columns and right-justification would take care of this annoyance, and unless there's a design requirement/limitation to prevent more than three lines of context or something, this would seem to be a simple conversion.