# Hot Meta Posts formatting needs a space

Tags: bug, design, community-bulletin

Looks like there is a styling issue in the "Hot Meta Posts" sidebar. Instead of speculating about the best fix, I'll leave a real solution to the devs but just wanted to point out this is a bit ugly atm.

**UPDATE:**
While I agree this is a dupe of [The Hot Meta Posts vote counter is too narrow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384507/the-hot-meta-posts-vote-counter-is-too-narrow), the latter does not provide an answer and did not so much as garner any response at all. This being the case, my hope is that we can re-open this one in hopes of getting attention from staff who may have missed it the first time around.

[image]

Comment: [Duplicate](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ameta.stackoverflow.com+hot+meta+posts+vote+spacing) of [The Hot Meta Posts vote counter is too narrow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/384507/4642212).

Comment: thanks.. I'd wholeheartedly agree to close except for the fact that the dupe is over a year old question and has no response or answer.  maybe we can leave this open since it may garner renewed attention

Comment: Clearly, I have to answer "No" to the question regarding the dupe: "Does this answer your question?"

Comment: _“Clearly, I have to answer ‘No’”_ — which is [another bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340009/289905) Stack Exchange needs to fix. Obviously, this is still a duplicate. Is [flagging for moderator attention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347959/289905) still a way to draw attention to old bugs and feature requests? Then that should be done on that question.

Comment: eh, adding a space won't fix it, and if a post with 1000 ever hits it it'l just happen again. Simply need to move the whole line of numbers 1-2 characters to the left (or remove them)

Comment: @KevinB - that would work.. or put a box around the count like "Related" and "Linked".

Comment: They've given the sidebar a width of 300px, added 32px of padding and then gone with a 12 col grid without gutters meaning they're stuck with giving the vote count either 22px or 44px and neither looks very good. I guess the quickest fix would be to just add some right-padding to the vote count column but then you're kind of messing with the grid and your designer will be mad.

Comment: I think this is why the `<table>` element was invented

Comment: `display: table-cell` (along with needed adjustments for parent elements) can also solve this issue without needing to change much.

Comment: Why does reopening this one make more sense than upvoting the old one? Or asking a moderator to feature the old one? Or asking a moderator to help get a [status-review] tag on the old one?

Comment: @HereticMonkey - I'm not 100% sure that it does. I've upvoted the old one but somehow I think it will be easier for staff to ignore an existing question than answer a new one. Don't ask me why... I recently asked [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/395901/how-are-we-doing-take-our-short-survey-how-are-we-doing-take-our-short-survey) which has a lot in common here: got closed as a dupe of another question reporting same issue with no real answer. Then got reopened and gained enough attention that staff took notice and there was renewed interest in providing a solution.